# How to get object which is inside array object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

```
 "DurationDetail" : {
  "Manual" : [ 
  {"Time" : "600000","Note" : "","TimeStamp" : ISODate("2017-01-13T06:12:22.485Z")}],
        "Automated" :{"Time" : "5000"}},
```

I want to access Manual.Time ? how to access that ?

Comment: `obj.DurationDetail.Manual[0].Time`, Note: `Manual` is an array hence `[]`

Answer (score 1):

I am feeling that your code is incomplete.It should be object.
Object should be

```
var obj = {
   "DurationDetail" : {
     "Manual" : [ 
     {"Time" : "600000","Note" : "","TimeStamp" : ISODate("2017-01-       13T06:12:22.485Z")}],
    "Automated" :{"Time" : "5000"}},
 }
```

ans is

```
obj.DurationDetail.Manual[0].Time
```

DurationDetail contains an object and Manual is array so you can access it by `obj.DurationDetail.Manual`.

0th Element contain an object with field Time.

Access by obj.DurationDetail.Manual[0].Time

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple array of manual then you can do it looping through manual array of duration detail object

```
for ( var i=0;i< DurationDetail.Manual.length;i++ )
 {
     console.log(DurationDetail.Manual[i].Time);
 }
```